# Does python copy objects on assignment?

Tags: python, copy, assign

I read that the assign in python does not copy it works like it does in c where it assigns a pointer to an object.

But when I debug this function:

```
def popall(self):
    objs = self.curstack
    self.curstack = []
    return objs
```

It looks like some kind of copy is taking place. After this function runs obis is full of things and **`self.curstack`** is empty…

So some copy is going on. Is it deep or shallow?

Comment: What's self.curstack at the first place? A list?

Comment: The below answers are pretty useful but the question is not very clear without knowing the value of self.curstack initially

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't copy anything.  It's just that assigning to `self.curstack` does not modify whatever `self.curstack` used to refer to.  It just makes `self.curstack` refer to something else.

Think of it this way.  `self.curstack` points to some stuff.  With `objs = self.curstack` you make `objs` point to that same stuff.  With `self.curstack = []`, you make `self.curstack` point to an empty list.  This doesn't remove any of the stuff that `self.curstack` used to point at; that stuff is still there and `objs` is still pointing at it.

[This article](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/) explains it using a nice analogy of label tags.

Answer (score 2):

Python uses references everywhere.  So your code works like this:

```
objs = self.curstack
```

Now `objs` points to whatever `curstack` was.

```
self.curstack = []
```

Now `curstack` points to an empty list.  `objs` is unchanged, and points to the old `curstack`.

```
return objs
```

You return `objs`, which is the old `curstack`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in all the answers that `self.curstack` doesn't modify it just refer to something. In you case it is referring to an empty list `[]`.

You can actually see the how objects are referring  using [**swampy**](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/)

```
 from swampy.Lumpy import Lumpy

class ref_test:

    def __init__(self, curstack):
        self.curstack = curstack

    def popall(self): 
        lampy = Lumpy()
        objs = self.curstack 
        self.curstack = [] 
        print id(self.curstack), id(objs)
        lampy.object_diagram()
        return objs

o = ref_test([1,2,3,4])
res = o.popall()
print res
```

[image]

As you can see `self.curstack` is pointing to an empty list and `objs` is still holding up the old values of `self.curstack`.

You can use [**id**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function to check “identity” of an object. Which is not unique in our case for `self.curstack` and `objs`

```
164711692 163838732
```

Comment: That Lumpy is neat! +1

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks. `Lumpy` really helps in understanding object reference.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there are two spaces, the namespace and the object space.

Names are just labels you assign to objects, which live in the object space. Objects have values and types; names are just there for our convenience; so that we may access things in the object space.

This is different than other languages like C where the variable is more like a box in which you can put a certain type of thing.

In Python, names can point to any object of any type - they are just aliases.

When you assign a name to an object, like this:

```
a = 1
```

`a` is just a label that points to the object `1` that has a type (int) and a value. If you next do this:

```
b = 1
```

Now you have two names `a` and `b` pointing to the same object - they are not "copies", but just two labels to the same object.

When you do this:

```
a = 'hello'
```

Now `a` is pointing to a new object, but `b` is still pointing to the old object (`1`).

Eventually, when no names are pointing to objects, Python does automatic garbage collection to keep the object space optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Let's demonstrate what's really going on  (using `id` which shows the location of the memory)

```
a = [1,2,3]
print id(a)
b = a
print id(b)
a = 4
print id(a)
print a
print b
```

> 4339130240
>
> 4339130240
>
> 4298163184
>
> 4
>
> [1, 2, 3]

So `a` and `b` initially point to the same place in memory, but then `a` points somewhere new.  But now, let's try

```
a = [1,2,3]
print id(a)
b = a
print id(b)
a[0] = 4
print id(a)
print a
print b
```

> 4339098040
>
> 4339098040
>
> 4339098040
>
> [4, 2, 3]
>
> [4, 2, 3]

So `b` isn't a fresh new copy of `a`.  It is the same object as `a` (when it's defined).  If you then do `a=4`, you're telling python, let's forget what `a` used to point to and assign a new meaning to it.  *4 does not appear in the spot in memory that `a` used to refer to*.  Instead `a` now refers to a new place in memory.  `b` still refers to what `a` initially referred to.

If we don't reassign `a`, but instead we change one of the things within the object that `a` points to, then checking `b` shows that the corresponding change happens to `b`.